# View.inflate vs LayoutInflater

Tags: android

What is the main difference in using `LayoutInflater` and static method `View.inflate()`? Are there any drawbacks in using any of them or maybe they serve different purposes?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If looking at the source of `View.inflate()` we see this:

```
public static View inflate(Context context, int resource, ViewGroup root) {
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return factory.inflate(resource, root);
}
```

So, internally, the `inflate()` method of `View` class uses the `LayoutInflater`, which makes me assume there's no difference.

Comment: You will want to have a local LayoutInflater if you are going to be inflating more than one view at a time, so it doesn't need to be recreated for every view.

Comment: static function also means you technically have a hidden dependency, which is gonna be bad for testing. Passing a layout inflater around at least you can mock it.

Answer (score 11):

`View.inflate()` does internally call `LayoutInflator.inflate(resource, root)` which in turn calls `LayoutInflator.inflate(resource, root, root != null)`.  The third parameter is booleanAttachToRoot which the docs describe as:

> Whether the inflated hierarchy should be attached to the root parameter? If false, root is only used to create the correct subclass of LayoutParams for the root view in the XML.

In other words, with `View.inflate()`, you can't tell the inflator *not* to attach your new view to the reference root ViewGroup.

Answer (score 0):

I just get a problem from that. And here is what I find.

View.inflate use LayoutInflator.inflate(id, Viewparent). It will ignore parent's layoutparam if Viewparent paramater is null.

But. Inflator.inflate has another api inflate(id, View parent, boolean attach). This method is useful when you need init this view with parent layoutparamter