# Inflate layout in Android Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I my code base I see two ways to inflate a layout in a Fragment, what is the difference? Is there a best practice?

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.mylayout, null);
}
```

Or :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false);
}
```

Comment: It depends on how you want to use or which one will best fit to your requirement. https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/understanding-androids-layoutinflater-inflate/ is a very good explanation for the same.

Answer (score 1):

See source of `View.inflate()`:

```
public static View inflate(Context context, int resource, ViewGroup root) {
        LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        return factory.inflate(resource, root);
}
```

So, internally, the `inflate()` method of `View` class uses the `LayoutInflater`, which makes me assume there's no difference.

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23909084/6891563)

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the first method View.inflate(getActivity(), R.layout.mylayout, null);
You'll see that it delegates the second inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, container, false);
So there is no difference between these ones.

Answer (score 0):

They both have literally same meaning and have no difference in run time